# how to handle deprecation messages from create-react-app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, dependencies, npm-install

I'm creating new react project by `npx create-react-app my-app`. It works fine. but when i delete the `node-modules` folder and use `npm install`,(same thing as cloning from remote repo) i get a lot of deprecation message. I'm not adding anything extra and the project runs fine but why am I getting all this deprecation messages ? can i do something about it or it is upto maintainers of various modules ?

node -v = v14.16.1

npm -v = 7.11.2

**deprecation messages -**

```
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-babel@4.4.0: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-babel.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's up to create-react-app maintainers to deal with this. The only thing you should do is to follow releases of "react-scripts" on github. So you would be up to date with fixes.

The only warnings you can fix are "peer dependencies" warnings ... You may install them ... or not :D